# Passing object HTMLInputElement as a parameter to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass a DOM element to a function without any luck. FireBug reports the following issue:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
LlenarDetalleReserva([object HTMLInputElement]); return false;
```

The selector needs to add a few attributes dynamically as it's being created.

I've tried the following:

```
$('#mySelector').attr({'onkeydown' : 'intOrFloat(event,this.value);', 'onchange' : 'LlenarDetalleReserva('+ $.trim($('#cant_r_'+ vectorid[2])[0]) +'); return false;'});
```

What am I missing here? What is producing this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you use attr to set onkeydown and onchange? `$('#mySelector').on('keydown', function(){}).on('change', function(){})` or `$('#mySelector').on({keydown: function(){}, change: function(){}});` They should't be attributes. Half of your issue is you have JS in strings, so you can't see syntax errors easily.

Comment: What's expected to be in `$.trim($('#cant_r_'+ vectorid[2])[0])`, other than `[object HTMLInputElement]` string? And shouldn't it be `$.trim($('#cant_r_'+ vectorid[2])[0].value)` actually?

Comment: Please show how `vectorid` is created or a dump of what it contains, and the function `LlenarDetalleReserva`

Comment: Popnoodles, I'd be happy with some feedback or suggestions on how you'd change it (regarding the attr()) :)


raina77ow, it's the DOM element that I want to pass as a parameter  `object HTMLInputElement`

Comment: @entiendoNull ok, I gave the suggestion / correct method in my comment. just spend a minute reading this page http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Just pass the ID `'LlenarDetalleReserva("cant_r_' + vectorid[2] + '")'` and have your function do the DOM selection.

Comment: Well, the function is already there and serves well calling it this way: `onchange="LlenarDetalleReserva(this);"` from the element that corresponds to `cant_r_' + vectorid[2]`

Comment: I see. In that case if you did want to do it using attributes, you'd probably want to change the function to do `if (typeof elem === "string") elem = $(elem);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, don't do that. Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind an event to the element. Never set it as an attribute directly.

```
$('#mySelector')
    .on('keydown', function(event) 
    {
        intOrFloat(event, this.value);
    })
    .on('change', function(event) 
    {
        if (vectorid && vectorid[2] != undefined)
        {
            var element = $('#cant_r_'+ vectorid[2]);

            if (element.length > 0)
            {
                LlenarDetalleReserva(element); 
            }
        }

        return false;
    });
```

The code above(full of `if`s) is made to avoid exceptions at run-time. That is what I would do in your case. Further, I don't really know what you're trying to get in that `$.trim()` function, but it seems that you want to get the element and pass it as a string. In the code above its being passed by reference, instead.

**UPDATE:**

In order to answer OP's question of *why I shouldn't set an attribute directly* I didn't tell you you can't add an attribute directly but an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) as attribute.I can't tell what happens in the backgrounds of the engine, so in fact, it works adding as attribute. But isn't a best practice and it's part of [Unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) approach.

Comment: Well, this worked almost perfectly. I did few a few changes to your code. Should I edit your example with the code that did it?

The $.trim() was just a desperate attempt to find a solution here.

Could you explain why I shouldn't set an attribute directly!
Thanks!!

Comment: @entiendoNull I have seen your updated code. Dude, don't use arrays directly like you did in the element selector. If it returns empty, you will get an run-time error.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But, as the selector is dynamic I see no other way here?